# Nested Query Assistance

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, natural-join

I need to use a nested query for this problem but I have never used nested queries before. Any help is appreciated. Here's the problem:
"List the names of those suppliers who ship a part that weighs more than 200 pounds."

Here's what I have using a Natural Join instead. But the problem requires a nested query.

```
SELECT Suppliers.sname 

FROM Suppliers NATURAL JOIN Shipments 

       NATURAL JOIN Parts

WHERE Shipments.quantity >= '1'

       AND Parts.weight > '200';
```

---

I tried it so far and this is what I have:

```
SELECT Suppliers.sname

FROM Suppliers, Shipments

WHERE Suppliers.snum = Shipments.snum

        AND Shipments.quantity >= ‘1’

        AND (

            SELECT Parts.weight

            FROM Parts
            ) > ‘200’;
```

Here's a link to the image of the ERD diagram:
http://tinypic.com/r/244qr74/8

Comment: You need to join shipment and parts on a column...what is that column?

Comment: There has to be a column in table Parts that would be able you to join the table Parts to either Supplier and/or Shipments. Once you find that you do not need nested query I think. i.e partId ?

Comment: Please add data structure of the tables to the question, otherwise we aren't able to answer. We need the column names on which you are joining in the first query.

Comment: Your subquery is not scalar. It returns a _set of_ values, which cannot be compared to a _single_ value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason they want you to use a nested query is that your natural join returns multiple records for a single supplier if that supplier has multiple shipments with parts weighing more than 200 pounds. Now, guessing your keys since they weren't supplied, I think they are looking for something like this:

```
Select s.sname Supplier
From Suppliers s
Where s.snum In(
               Select Distinct sh.snum 
               From Shipments sh
                   Natural Join Parts p
               Where p.Weight > 200)
```

**EDIT** I have updated the query to use the snum key name as displayed on your updated pic.

Comment: I added a photo of the ERD that accompanies the question. Maybe that will help clarify a little more.

Comment: You are quite welcome! I'm happy to help :) Let me know if there is anything else I can help you with. Also, please consider marking this as the answer and voting it up. Thanks!

Comment: I wish I could vote it up, but I'm a noob to Stack Overflow so I don't have 15 reputation. LOL.